# Error Invalid default value for 'updated_at' phpmyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

i have a question concerning phpMyAdmin, I am trying to create the following table, but keep having this error, anyone knows where this is coming from?

The table I want to create:

```
CREATE TABLE products(
pid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(100) not null,
price decimal(10,2) not null,
description text,
created_at timestamp default now(),
updated_at timestamp
);
```

The error:

```
SQL query:


CREATE TABLE products(
pid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(100) not null,
price decimal(10,2) not null,
description text,
created_at timestamp default now(),
updated_at timestamp
)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'updated_at'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of NOW() you should use [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

```
CREATE TABLE products(
pid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(100) not null,
price decimal(10,2) not null,
description text,
created_at timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
updated_at timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Also, you should set default values for NOT NULL constraints, so your final creation script should look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    pid INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```